# Check join condition of a relationship in SqlAlchemy

Tags: sqlalchemy

Say I have a grouped parent / child relationship, with composite foreign keys, like this:

```
class Group(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'group'
    id_ = Column('id', GUID, primary_key=True)

class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'parent'
    id_ = Column('id', GUID, primary_key=True)
    group_id = Column(GUID, ForeignKey('group.id'), primary_key=True)

    group = relationship(Group)

class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'child'
    id_ = Column('id', GUID, primary_key=True)
    group_id = Column(GUID, ForeignKey('group.id'), primary_key=True)
    parent_id = Column(GUID)

    __table_args__ = (
        ForeignKeyConstraint(
            ['parent_id', 'group_id'],
            ['parent.id', 'parent.group_id']
        ),
    )

    group = relationship(Group)
    parent = relationship(Parent, foreign_keys=[parent_id], backref='children')
```

My **actual question** is: how can I find out what the join condition would be? I'm hoping for something like `Child.parent.join_condition`

Bonus points: will `Child.parent` produce a join condition like this: `ON (child.group_id = parent.group_id AND child.parent_id = parent.id)` Or do I need to be explicit and use a `primaryjoin` argument? *Edit* I just re-read [this section of the docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/join_conditions.html#overlapping-foreign-keys), and it looks like it won't.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to use `primaryjoin` in this case. It is enough to define `foreign_keys` by including `group_id` as well:

```
class Child(Base):
    ...
    parent = relationship(
        Parent,
        foreign_keys=[parent_id, group_id],
        backref='children',
    )
```

In this case including join like:

```
q = session.query(Child).join(Parent)
print(q)
```

will produce:

```
SELECT  child.id AS child_id,
        child.group_id AS child_group_id,
        child.parent_id AS child_parent_id
FROM    child
JOIN    parent
    ON  parent.group_id = child.group_id
    AND parent.id = child.parent_id
```

*Note: one does not need parenthesis around the `ON` condition.*

Comment: Thanks! But when I do that, it complains that the ownership of `group_id` is ambiguous: `SAWarning: relationship 'Child.parent' will copy column
parent.group_id to column child.group_id,
which conflicts with...`. Anyway, my question was really about whether it's possible to see the join clause of a `relationship` so I can check it.

Comment: I see. Will need to understand what you are doing which results in this error.  I have a simple self-contained test script which works for what I showed.

Comment: I think it's because the `Child.group` relationship also wants to write to the `group_id` column, which may conflict with the value written by `Child.parent`.

Comment: This does not happy while executing `query` though, right? It is when you are creating new objects? Could you share the minimum sample code which generates this error?